# Database Project failing on Azure Dev Ops build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, database-project

Bringing a client old win forms application into our development ecosystem.  Part of the effort is putting their db under source control with a database project.

When I build locally (VS 2017) - I get a bunch of warnings that some of the stored procs / functions reference objects that do not exists.

For Example:

```
Warning:  SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[proc_WORKORDERDETAILUpdate] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[WORKORDERDETAIL].[WORKERORDERNUMBER].
```

In this particular scenario - the entire table is missing from the database.

The stored procs in the db are out of date.  Obviously they are not being used.  I am not trying to fix this whole mess now.  Just get the app and db under source control.

When I check this in - the build definition is failing on the database project.  The warnings I get locally are now treated as hard errors on the build server.

```
Error SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[proc_WORKORDERDETAILUpdate] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[WORKORDERDETAIL].[WORKERORDERNUMBER].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  Rookie mistake.

I had the "Treat warnings as Errors" box unchecked for the debug configuration - hence why I was fine locally.

My release (build server) configuration is was not the same.  It was not until I looked at the project.sqlproj xml file that saw the differences.

I leave this here just in case anyone else runs into a build server problem that cannot be replicated locally.  Maybe it will give them a pointer.